# Cordova SQLitePlugin having the "images" table not found

Tags: android, ios, sqlite, cordova, mbtiles

I'm actually working on a cordova application that is reading (not writing) a .mbtiles file. That is a database filed with tiles in order to show an offline map with leaflet.

Everything concerning the file (call it test.mbtiles) is working : downloading and openning. But there is still a big issue. I'm not able to read the tables. Here's the non functionnal sample of my code :

```
getTileUrl: function (tilePoint, callBack) {
    var x = tilePoint.x;
    var y = tilePoint.y;
    var z = tilePoint.z;

    var base64Prefix = 'data:image/png;base64,';

    var db2 = new window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: 'test.mbtiles'});

    db2.transaction(function(tx) {

        tx.executeSql("SELECT tile_data FROM images INNER JOIN map ON images.tile_id = map.tile_id WHERE zoom_level = ? AND tile_column = ? AND tile_row = ?", [z, x, y], function (tx, res) {

                if(res.rows.length>0) {
                    console.log("success");
                    var src = base64Prefix + res.rows.item(0).tile_data;
                    callBack(src);
                }
                else {
                    console.log("response : no data");
                }
                }, function (tx, er) {
                    console.log('error with executeSql : ', er.message);
                    return;
                });
            });
   }
```

So now everytime I try to use the offline map (using tiles from the test.mbtiles which is present on the device) i get this error :

```
error with executeSql :  no such table: images (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT tile_data FROM images INNER JOIN map ON images.tile_id = map.tile_id WHERE zoom_level = ? AND tile_column = ? AND tile_row = ?
```

So I assume that the file I'm getting, the test.mbtiles is not good because it doesn't have any `images` table. But that's wrong. I used `SQLite Database Browser` in order to look at my database scheme, and found that the `images` table is here and filled with the right data.

Has anyone else had this error and know how to fix it ?

Btw I'm using latest release versions of SQLite Plugin and Cordova, and mainly testing on android (will port to ios if android works). And as much as possible i would like to use only .js files, no addition in any java class or such (would destroy the whole workflow).

Thanks.

Comment: Into what directory did you put the database file?

Comment: I'm downloading it from a remote server using filetransfer and filesystem. Basically the downloading code is : `ft.download(remoteFile, fs.root.toURL() + '/test.mbtiles', function (entry) {`. The file is openning, i can access the `map` table for instance. But I can't find a way to use the `images` table.

Comment: So the downloaded file is in the `/` directory? And you are opening a database in your app's directory?

Comment: The database opening seems to be working because, as I said, I can still use the `map` table. But it's really not what I need. I'll check a few things regarding the file location, but I'm pretty sure the file I'm opening is the file I downloaded earlier. If you think this is the only place the problem could come from I'll double check it.

Comment: you can query the meta data table **sqlite_master** e.g `SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'` and check whether the table exists and if it exists which schema it exist?

Answer (score 1):

The MBTiles spec [stores tiles in a table called `tiles`, not `images`](https://github.com/mapbox/mbtiles-spec/blob/master/1.2/spec.md#schema-1).